# Multiple jars causing error.How can I find unused and duplicate jars in my project

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson, jersey, jersey-client

I am getting this error only in production environment(not running it in eclipse).

Please find the sample code for your reference:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                        .header("username", "user")
                                        .header("password", "pass")
                                        .post(ClientResponse.class);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ response.getStatus());
}

String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Also I am getting an exception something like below.Can you please review it:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:549)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
```

at line:

```
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Also please find the dependencies in class Path of my project

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/activation.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/antlr-2.7.5H3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/asm.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-collections.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1-rc1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/dom.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/ehcache-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/java-json.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxb-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxb-impl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxb1-impl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxrpc-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxrpc-impl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxrpc-spi.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jaxws-rt.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-apache-client-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-atom-abdera-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-bundle-1.10-b01.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-client-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jersey-simple-server-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jta.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/mail.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Include all libraries relate to jersey-media-json-jackson

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.31</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed all jersy related jars other than jersey-bundle-1.10-b01.jar